# Call destructor upon manual termination of the program

Tags: c++, destructor

Suppose I have an instance of a class. Will the destructor be called automatically if I terminate the program manually (say, by pressing the cross icon in the CLI window)? If not, is there any option to make the destructor be called upon manual termination of the program?

Comment: Please tell what details are needed before closing the post. To me everything is absolutely clear.

Comment: You may want to check how `std::terminate` works, and what you essentially can do there.

Comment: On the operating systems that I'm familiar with, terminating the program manually does not have an opportunity to call the destructors.  The program just stops where ever it is at, and then the process (and any associated threads) are halted, and the memory returned to the operating system, and any other resources acquired by the program are relinquished.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specified by the C++ standard. What happens depends entirely on your operating system, and your program.

However, nothing that happens in your program should be a big mystery of this kind. What happens with your program is controlled entirely by your program's logic.

So, you simply need to answer the following question, by yourself: did you write any code in your program, yourself, that explicitly checks if this close button is pushed, and if so your program performs an orderly termination, returning from `main`, and destroying all objects, including the one you are asking about?

So unless you've actually written any code to that effect, it is not going to happen. Your operating system will kill the process and it immediately stops.

> If not, is there any option to make the destructor be called upon
> manual termination of the program?

There's certainly a way to do that, this sounds like fairly basic task. You'll just have to actually write the code to do that. How to do that depends entirely on your operating system, and your operating system libraries. There is no single answer to this question that applies to every operating system in the world, from MS-Windows, to Mac OSX to Linux. Each one of these does it in their own way, and there are often different operating system libraries, where this task would be implemented in its own way.

Consult your operating system's development libraries for more information.

Comment: Does it matter whether I abort the execution by pressing the cross icon or by pressing the stop button in the Visual Studio interface? I mean, is it considered the same or again depends on OS stuff or sth else?

Comment: The answer would be the same. Your computer is not going to invent its own code, and add it to your own program, by itself. Programs that do such a thing are called "viruses". Everything that happens in your program happens because you wrote the code that does it. Unless you've explicitly written any logic for something, it's not going to happen. The only thing that can possibly happen outside of your program's control is the operating system terminating the process, which stops everything in its tracks.